# past perfect to emphasize the completion of the event

Tags: past-tense

is it possible to use past perfect to emphasize the completion of the event

For example,

> I *had created* a guest account on my computer and it was ready to work so if you need it don't hesitate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in the sentence. While you are right that the past perfect shows that the event was completed in the past, it does not mean that the effects are *still intact*.

> I had created a guest account on my computer and it was ready to work...

Till that point, the sentence is okay but the moment you added the condition in the *present tense* (so, if you *need it...*) it has a mismatch. The event was created and then the story was over. Now, if you need something in present, the sentence structure should be changed.

> I *have created* a guest account on my computer, and it *is* ready to work. So, if you need it, don't hesitate (to ask for it).

The need is in present and conditional, that's why you need to use *have created* that will denote that the event is completed but effects are still there.